# jQuery jQRangeSlider Plugin Not Working With FLOT

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using the latest FLOT release for my chart control.
I wanted to add a slider control that would allow for changing the window of the data based on the date of the data.
I have tried multiple slider jQuery-UI controls and found that [jQRangeSlider](https://github.com/ghusse/jQRangeSlider) plugin looks to be the best bet.
The issue is that it looks like FLOT is using a particular instance of jQuery (jquery.js in its script path) and jQRangeSlider wants another particular version. How can I have two instances of jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

According to its documentation, FLOT is requiring jQuery 1.2.6 or greater. But it's delivered with jQuery 1.5.2.

jQRangeSlider is delivered with jQuery 1.4.4

I'm pretty sure that jQRangeSlider will work with jQuery 1.5.2. Just give a try.